# TSQL Conditional Where or Group By?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, case

I have a table like the following:

```
id | type        | duedate
-------------------------
 1 | original    | 01/01/2017
 1 | revised     | 02/01/2017
 2 | original    | 03/01/2017
 3 | original    | 10/01/2017
 3 | revised     | 09/01/2017
```

Where there may be either one or two rows for each id.  If there are two rows with same id, there would be one with type='original' and one with type='revised'.  If there is one row for the id, type will always be 'original'.

What I want as a result are all the rows where type='revised', but if there is only one row for a particular id (thus type='original') then I want to include that row too.  So desired output for the above would be:

```
id | type        | duedate
 1 | revised     | 02/01/2017
 2 | original    | 03/01/2017
 3 | revised     | 09/01/2017
```

I do not know how to construct a WHERE clause that conditionally checks whether there are 1 or 2 rows for a given id, nor am I sure how to use GROUP BY because the revised date could be greater than or less than than the original date so use of aggregate functions MAX or MIN don't work.  I thought about using CASE somehow, but also do not know how to construct a conditional that chooses between two different rows of data (if there are two rows) and display one of them rather than the other.

Any suggested approaches would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this sufficient?

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable m1
WHERE type='revised'
 or 1=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable m2 WHERE m2.id=m1.id)
```

Comment: I really like this - takes away the reliance on the text in 'type' being in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 4):

you can use row number for this.

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Type DESC) AS RN
FROM YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery to take the `MAX([type])`.  In this case it works for [type] since alphabetically we want revised first, then original and "r" comes after "o" in the alphabet.  We can then INNER JOIN back on the same table with the matching conditions.

```
SELECT T2.*
  FROM (
         SELECT id, MAX([type]) AS [MAXtype]
           FROM myTABLE
         GROUP BY id
       ) AS dT INNER JOIN myTable T2 ON dT.id = T2.id AND dT.[MAXtype] = T2.[type]
ORDER BY T2.[id]
```

Gives output:

```
id  type      duedate
1   revised   2017-02-01
2   original  2017-03-01
3   revised   2017-09-01
```

Here is the sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14121f/6/0